# Photoshop: How to make image clearer when print out

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have below image. This is a scan paper, and when print out, it's too blur. 
[image: scan image]

I want to use Photoshop for editing this image, so printer print out will be clearer. I don't know this question is suitable on on this site or not. If not, I don't know which tutorial online help me do this work. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please see the duplicate link above your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Scaling up go to menu : image -> image size
2. Change Size to 300%, checkbox : Resample
3. Filter -> Sharpen -> Unsharp Mark

Comment: Smart sharpen might be a bit better!

Comment: Yes Smart sharpen easy and better

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Photoshop - it's about your printer. First of all, when scanning, make sure you scan at a reasonable DPI (otherwise you will get a low resolution image that will of course look bad when printed). Secondly, make sure when printing you apply the correct settings for your printer and that you did not resize the image, edit the DPI or chosen the wrong page type.

If the original document is small (ie a5) and you are scaling it up to an a4, then PS may be of some assistance - use Sharpening and Levels to improve the readability of the document.